# python dataframe count word occurrences

Tags: python, dataframe, count

I have searched a lot here and I couldnt find the answer for it.
I have a dataframe with column "Descriptions" which contain a long string,
I'm trying to count the number of occurence for a specific word "restaurant",

```
df['has_restaurants'] = 0
for index,text in enumerate(df['Description']):
    text = text.split()
    df['has_restaurants'][index] = (sum(map(lambda count : 1 if 'restaurant' in count else 0, text)))
```

Did the above and it works but it doesn't look like a good way to do it and it generates this "error" as well:

```
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['has_restaurants'][index] = (sum(map(lambda count : 1 if 'restaurant' in count else 0, text)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might simplify that by using `.str.count` method, consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"description":["ABC DEF GHI","ABC ABC ABC","XYZ XYZ XYZ"]})
df['ABC_count'] = df.description.str.count("ABC")
print(df)
```

output

```
   description  ABC_count
0  ABC DEF GHI          1
1  ABC ABC ABC          3
2  XYZ XYZ XYZ          0
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! so simple, god I'm stupid. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer to your question, so it may help others in the future

Comment: True, do you know what to do if I want to count more than one word?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's native `.count()` method:

```py
df['has_restaurants'] = 0
for index,text in enumerate(df['Description']):
    df['has_restaurants'][index] = text.count('restaurant')
```